# ARM ASM Segfaulting at function end

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault, arm

I have the following ARM assembly code. The purpose is to print out a 32-bit integer in hexadecimal character by character. The function prototype for this assembly function is `printx(int, int)` where the first `int` is the integer to be printed, and the second is a flag to specify whether it should be printed in uppercase or lowercase hex. The data variables are there for when I tried debugging the code myself by comparing printf output and the output from my code.

```
.data

derp: .asciz "\nDerp\n"
hex: .asciz "HEX %x\n"
dec: .asciz "\nDEC %d\n"
count: .asciz "\nCOUNT %d\n"

.text

.global printx

printx:
    push {fp, lr}
    mov fp, sp

    mov r11, #1         // firstloop counter "i"
firstloop:              // loop to extract hex character
    cmp r11, #1         // if i == 1
    beq endsecond       // jump to end of loop (no shift necessary)
    lsr r0, r0, #4      // logical shift right 4 bits
endsecond:
    and r4, r0, #0xf    // gets first 4 bits
    cmp r4, #9          // is it greater than 9?
    bgt alpha           // jump to alpha
    add r4, r4, #48     // add 48 to get ascii for number
    b beta              // jump to beta
alpha:
    cmp r1, #1          // if uppercase flag is set
    beq upper           // jump to upper
    add r4, r4, #87     // add 87 to get ascii for lowercase letters
    b beta              // jump to beta
upper:
    add r4, r4, #55     // add 55 to get ascii for uppercase letters
beta:
    push {r4}           // push ascii character onto stack
    cmp r11, #8         // if i == 8
    beq popping         // branch to popping
    add r11, #1         // i++
    b firstloop         // branch to firstloop
popping:
    mov r10, #1          // let r9 indicate leading (1 is true)
poploop:
    pop {r0}            // pop into r5
    cmp r0, #0          // if r5 != 0
    bne nonzero         // branch to nonzero
    cmp r10, #1          // if r10 == 1 (if leading)
    beq counter         // branch to counter
    b print             // branch to print
nonzero:
    mov r10, #0          // set leading (r10) to false (0)
print:
    bl putchar          // call putchar
counter:
    sub r11, #1         // i--
    cmp r11, #0         // if i != 0
    bne poploop         // branch to poploop
    ldr r0, =derp
    bl printf

    mov sp, fp
    pop {fp, pc}
.end
```

When I run `gdb`, I get the following:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
counter () at printinteger.s:62
62      pop {fp, pc}
```

I've double-checked that I'm popping exactly as many times as I'm pushing onto the stack, so I think it may have something to do with how I'm popping the frame pointer and program counter, based on the gdb, or I'm moving the stack pointer to the wrong place. Any help diagnosing the problem would be appreciated.

Comment: `bl printf` - is this a C standard lib printf or something written by you? (same question for `putchar`). If it's a C one - you don't seem to use it correctly, if it's yours - we need to see it.

Comment: @tum_ it is the c standard lib printf and putchar. Could you point out what the proper usage would be? It seems to be working fine, printing out the right chars I pass to it

Comment: deleted the comment as I need to wake up first ;) went to grab a coffee...

Comment: EABI requires that r4 to r11 are preserved by a function to if you call this from C you have undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You corrupt the `sp` of the caller because `fp` and `r11` are synonyms, so your `mov r11, #1` overwrites your `fp` and you copy this garbage into `sp` at the end of your function as a result.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you! I didn’t know fp and r11 were synonymous.

Comment: Glad I could help.  `I didn’t know fp and r11..`- you live and you learn.. ARM32 registers are R0 .. R15, any other name you see in the code is a synonym of some Rxx. PC,LR,SP are normally learnt straightaway (in fact, I wouldn't be surprised if some people are not aware that these are R15,R14,R13). FP (R11) and IP (R12) come later...